# How to count the number of distinct equivalence classes for a relation involving truth tables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am having trouble with question 22 part (2):

[image]

Here is the solution:

[image]

How did the author know that there are 256 distinct equivalence classes? Where did they get $2^8$ from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave out any intermediate working, a truth table for some statement involving $p,q,r$ is simply a list of the truth values of the statement for all possible truth values of $p,q,r$.  Now $p,q,r$ can each be true or false so overall there are $2^3=8$ options (that is, $8$ rows in the truth table), and to specify the truth values of your statement you have to make $8$ choices from $\{T,F\}$.  You can make the same choice more than once (in fact you have to), and the order is important, so the number of choices is $2^8$.

Comment: I don't understand where you got $2^3$ from but I understand that there are 8 rows in the truth table so that's alright that I don't understand that bit. However, I also don't understand where you got $2^8$ from. Why do you have to make 8 choices from $\{T,F\}$? Don't you have to make 24 choices? One choice per square, right? And the grid is 8x3.

Comment: Oh, I see why you have to make 8 choices now. This is about the results of the truth table. I understand that you have to make the same choice more than once and the order is important, but where do you get that the number of choices is $2^8$?

Comment: Think of it like this: you have your $8$-row truth table with all possible truth values filled in for $p,q,r$, and eight blank squares for the truth values of your statement.  There are two options for the first blank, $T$ or $F$.  Then there are two for the second, total so far $2\times2$.  Then the same two options for the third square, number of choices so far $2\times2\times2$, and so on.

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense now.